# Couchbase : how to define or register a view in Couchbase server using libcouchbase C API

Tags: c, nosql, couchbase

My software is "C" based and is using libcouchbase to talk to Couchbase server
I know how to query Couchbase views using libcouchbase.
But to be able to query the view I need to create one.

I understand that the view can be created through the couchbase GUI.
But when the software is shipped as a product I dont want to give the instructions to create the view separately.
Hence I am looking for a libcouchbcase API which can create the view from the Couchbase C client itself.This will be a onetime activity when the product startsup(In other words its an idempotent operation)

Any code snippets are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man lcb_make_http_request` to get more info about doing restful queries to couchbase

Also you can find doc sources in the repo https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase/blob/master/man/man3couchbase/lcb_make_http_request.3couchbase.txt#L147-163

```
const char *docid = "_design/test";
const char *doc = "{\"views\":{\"all\":{\"map\":\"function (doc, meta) { emit(meta.id, null); }\"}}}";
lcb_http_cmd_t cmd;
lcb_http_request_t req;
cmd.version = 0;
cmd.v.v0.path = docid;
cmd.v.v0.npath = strlen(docid);
cmd.v.v0.body = doc;
cmd.v.v0.nbody = strlen(doc);
cmd.v.v0.method = LCB_HTTP_METHOD_PUT;
cmd.v.v0.content_type = "application/json";
lcb_error_t err = lcb_make_http_request(instance, NULL,
                                        LCB_HTTP_TYPE_VIEW,
                                        &cmd, &req);
if (err != LCB_SUCCESS) {
    ... failed to schedule request ...
```

Comment: Thanks @avsej - An input - I guess this info is difficult to find, may be I am wrong , may be I didnt try hard enough to get it.